# String of bits to binary format Python

Tags: python, binary

This seems really simple but I can't figure it out.
I have a string of bits in a string format and want to convert it to a binary format.
I assumed placing the string inside of the bin() function would work but it doesn't.

```
string = "01101"

print(bin(string))
```

Comment: Take a look: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "01101"
print(bin(int(string,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by binary format.

Here's a few examples of what you can do:

```py
>>> int('01101', 2)
13

>>> number = 13

>>> bin(number)
'0b1101'

>>> oct(number)
'0o15'

>>> hex(number)
'0xd'

>>> f'{number:08b}'
'00001101'
```

Comment: Didn't realize you could specify a base within the int function, thanks.